# How to address a reader and a postdoctoral research assistant?

Tags: email, germany, titles, india

I want to send an email to two people. One of them is a reader in India and the other is a postdoctoral research assistant in Germany. I do not know how to address each of them at the start of the email - “Dear Professor", "Dear Dr.” or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What salutation to use for someone with a PhD who is a Lecturer or Reader in the UK?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28013/what-salutation-to-use-for-someone-with-a-phd-who-is-a-lecturer-or-reader-in-the)

Comment: @Allure This is about Germany, not UK.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano But India does use Commonwealth academic job titles.

Comment: @origimbo **"the other is a postdoctoral research assistant in Germany"**

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively as I don't have direct experience of India or Germany, hence the comment rather than answer, but I'd suggest sticking with "Dr".. India seems to use UK titles, in which a Reader is not a Professor - and Germany is a stickler for titles and if this person was a Professor you would know about it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formal way to address a postdoc in Germany would be Dr. [Surname]. My experience is that at least among Phd students/Postdocs people will quickly switch to an informal first-name address. 
But for first contact you should use the formal Dr. [Surname].