# How can I appropriately call my professor?

Tags: etiquette, professorship

I'm an undergraduate student in a research group. I'm a little bit confused about how can I call my professor appropriately. The graduate students in the group just call him by his name, but I think it would be a little bit rude for me to do that. I want to be more polite, but I also feel like it's a bit weird if I add 'Dr./'Prof.' every time I'm trying to call him. Any suggestions about what I could do?

Comment: Have you asked the professor how they would prefer to be addressed? And which country are you in?

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16886/after-initial-contact-how-long-should-i-address-a-professor-as-dr-smith-or

Comment: @astronat Thanks for the comment! I'm in the U.S. No I haven't ask my professor about that